# unexpected end of stream when parsing large XML file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read a large XML file from the web to my android application and to parse the results
After I'm opening the InputStream and trying to parse it to a Document I getting the following error:
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream

Here is my code:

```
url = new URL(urlAddress);
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the web server terminated the connection before the app had read it all?

Comment: Seeing this is a mobile device you might want to download the xml first, and then parse. You could warn the user if downloading was only partial (in case of connection problems).